# How to add an ajax autosearch collection in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an active admin page called `vendor` that has a list of `user` in my model written as:

```
has_many :users do
def staff_users
   where('staff_user' = true)
end
```

In my `vendor` active admin form I need to make an autocomplete search for users that I can add to my staff_users (I have the function already working).

I just need to get the available list of users as a collection on my front end.

I've seen this gem [select2](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/select2_search.md) from `activeadminaddons` and installed it using `gem install activeadmin_addons`. I was trying to use it, however I'm having a problem understanding what is the `url` for.

Is it correct that I need to create a method on my `vendors_controller` that can be mapped in my `routes.rb` that will return all `User`?

If what I understood is not what it's supposed to do, can someone please explain to me what and how to connect the `url` param in active admin [select2](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/select2_search.md) `activeadminaddons`.

Any other ideas too? Maybe without the use of this gem, there's a simple solution I can integrate what I need in active admin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try running `rake routes` and find the `collection_url` for your `Vendor` model. I guess it will be something like: `admin_vendors_path`. This route has been dynamically created by registering your model through ActiveAdmin.

Maybe try reading more at: https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/select2_search.md